# Why does sum(4 >= my_array)) print 6 instead of 10 (because the array starts from 0)?

Tags: python

```
my_array = np.concatenate((np.arange(10**6), np.array([4])))
my_array

array([     0,      1,      2, ..., 999998, 999999,      4])
print(sum(4 >= my_array))
```

Output: `6`

This print statement will print 6 instead of 10 which from what I understand should be (0+1+2+3+4)

I assume that sum(4>=my_array) does not sum the first the elements up to or equal to 4 and it works in another way?

Comment: It should print `1`, because there is only one zeros in the array, did you mean `print(sum(4 >= my_array))`

Comment: I think you meant to ask why `print(sum(4>=my_array))` prints 6.  In your array the values that are less than or equal to 4 are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 4.  That's six items. The `>=` comparison returns an array of booleans, where 1 is True and 0 is False.  Add up six True and you get six.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`4 >= my_array` is testing your values in your array if they are equal or lower than 4. Since you have 6 values that are equal or lower than 4 in your array, you have 6 times `True`. `sum()` sums  `True` as 1 and `False` as 0, which is why you get 6.

You want to do

```
>>> sum(my_array[my_array<=4])
14
```

(although in this case you get 14 because you concatenated 4 at the end, so you have 0+1+2+3+4+4)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `print(sum(4 >= my_array))`, this returns `6`.

There are indeed 6 values lower or equal to 4, the first 5 ones:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

The one you added at the end: `4`

This is easily seen if you just concatenate a short array:

```
my_array = np.concatenate((np.arange(10), np.array([4])))
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4])
#        *  *  *  *  *                 *   6 values ≤ 4
```

**But why does `sum` give 6?** because `4 >= my_array` returns booleans `[True, True, True, ..., False, True]`. Each `True` counts for `1` and `False` for `0`.

You rather want:

```
my_array[4>=my_array].sum()
# 14
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are referring to '4' in an array, it instead means the index of the array not the value that is in the array:

```
example we say array[3]
array = [3, 1, 2, 0, 4]
  index |0 |1 |2 |3 |4
it outputs '0' from the array
```

'sum(4>=my_array)' does not work the way you think it does, sum cannot sum if the object is not iterable, such as a tuple, the '(4 >= my_array) is relational which returns *True* and *False*, it only checks if 'my_array' is equal or less than the integer '4' which will result an error because you are trying to compare values that is a tuple (my_array) and an int (4), you can however access a specific item in the array like:

```
print(my_array[4] >= my_array[1]) # *True
#if you were trying to compare values in a tuple but if you want to sum the values in an array just:*

print(sum(array)) # *10*
```

*If the object is iterable*

Also I don't know what you're trying to do with (10**6), are you trying to sum it with 'my_array' ?